# Yii2: REST API - 404 error

Tags: php, rest, yii2

DataBase has table with saved Tweets.

There is controller:

```
<?php

namespace app\controllers;

use yii\rest\ActiveController;

class TweetController extends ActiveController
{
    public $modelClass = 'app\models\Tweet';
}
```

Corresponding model `app\model\Tweet` created by `gii`.

In `app\web\config` added:

```
..............
    'components' => [
        'urlManager' => [
            'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
            'enableStrictParsing' => true,
            'showScriptName' => false,
            'rules' => [
                ['class' => 'yii\rest\UrlRule',
                 'controller' => 'tweet'],
            ],
        ],
        'request' => [
                 'parsers' =>['application/json' => 'yii\web\JsonParser', ],
        ],
...............
```

In `app\web` added `.htaccess` according http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-tutorial-shared-hosting.html

In `apache` DocumentRoot as `app\web`

According yii2 docs: `curl -i -H "Accept:application/json" "http://localhost/tweets"` must return paged model data. Instead of this:

```
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Date: Tue, 29 Mar 2016 14:04:05 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu)
Content-Length: 278
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>404 Not Found</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Not Found</h1>
<p>The requested URL /tweets was not found on this server.</p>
<hr>
<address>Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) Server at localhost Port 80</address>
</body></html>
```

Also tryed - urlManager `'controller' => ['tw' => 'tweet']` whit according url.

why there is 404? Guided by http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-rest-quick-start.html

added: well... url should be `http://localhost/index.php/tweets` but it`s not obviously for me.

Comment: please show all code of your TweetController Code

Comment: Are you using the basic template or advanced? which directory is your project ..?

Comment: basic template. Em what do you mean "which"? yii2 - name.

Comment: You project is save in an directory ... the path of your project dir ... eg: localhost/mybasicproject

Comment: I have post an answer with a first sugestion

Comment: Try setting `'enableStrictParsing' => false,`

Comment: when in strictparsing mode, controller != controller/index

Answer (score 1):

The path should be

```
  http:://localhost/yii2/tweets
```

or

```
 http:://localhost/yii2/index.php/tweets
```

(depending by the correct configuration of urlManager)

try also

```
  http:://localhost/yii2/tweets/index
```

or

```
 http:://localhost/yii2/index.php/tweets/index
```

could be you can find useful this tutorial http://budiirawan.com/setup-restful-api-yii2/

Comment: Yep, i read that guide, but i try find why... i done same as quick start guide. But in my case is url  `http://localhost/index.php/tweets` i dont understand why there is a difference

Answer (score 1):

I also got the same problem.This is my solution,which worked well for me(Apache 2.2).
**Editing the apache2.conf file and changing the AllowOverride from None to All. Then restart Apache Service **

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, I set `'enableStrictParsing' => false` and it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

add followings lines to your controller:

```
protected function verbs() {
   $verbs = parent::verbs();
    $verbs =  [
        'index' => ['GET', 'POST', 'HEAD'],
        'view' => ['GET', 'HEAD'],
        'create' => ['POST'],
        'update' => ['PUT', 'PATCH']
    ];
   return $verbs;
}
```

Comment: Although this may solve the issue, please consider explaining why this works.

Answer (score 0):

I just encountered this issue and spent some time tracing through the code to find that you must have an alias defined for your project. Without that, it cannot load your controllers.

I am working in a Yii2 advanced template setup where I have this structure:

```
/common
/mainApp
/api
```

In `/common/config/bootstrap.php`, I had to add:

```php
Yii::setAlias('@api', dirname(dirname(__DIR__)) . '/api');
```

This allows the controller find and load/create process in the Yii 2 framework to work correctly. Without it, the class_exists check in `yii2\base\Module.php` on line 637 will fail and cause the request to result in a 404.

Hope this helps someone!

~Cheers :)